# Prove that $\forall n\ge2\in \mathbb{N}$ ${\prod\limits_{j=1}^{n}(2j)!}>[(n+1)!]^n$

Tags: inequality, factorial

How would you prove this? Would you use induction?

Prove that $$\forall n\ge2\in \mathbb{N}$$

$${\prod\limits_{j=1}^{n}(2j)!}>[(n+1)!]^n$$

Comment: Can you write down your attempt so far? Verification comes later. Even to help you, we need an understanding of what you've done.

Comment: Hello. So far, I've tried to link the fact that $$(2j)!>(n+1)!$$ and use it in the expression above, given that both parts are a product of n terms. I also tried using that as a hypothesis and arrive to an absurd.

Finally, just now, I wrote the expression $${\prod\limits_{j=1}^{n}(2j)!}$$ as $$((2j)!)!$$ and argue that $$\forall n\ge2\in \mathbb{N}$$ you have that $$((2jn)!)! > [(n+1)!]^n$$. 
But I'm not sure if this is right, or even useful.

Comment: Sorry, typo: I meant that last line to be: $$((2n)!)! > [(n+1)!]^n$$

Comment: Any thoughts? @Macavity ?

Answer (score 2):

You can prove it by direct computation. Show

$${\prod\limits_{j=1}^{n}(2j)!}>[(n+1)!]^n$$

Write what you have on the LHS and RHS:

$$
(1 \cdot 2) \cdot (1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4) \cdots
> 1^n \cdot 2^n \cdots (n+1)^n$$

$$
1^n \cdot 2^n \cdot 3^{n-1} \cdot 4^{n-1}     \cdots (2 j -1)^{n+1-j} \cdot
(2 j)^{n+1-j} \cdots  (2 n - 1) \cdot (2 n) > 1^n \cdot 2^n \cdots (n+1)^n$$

Now divide by all terms up to base (n+1):

Let $n$ be even (odd $n$ works equivalently):
$$ 
(n+2)^{n/2} \cdot (n+3)^{n/2 -1} \cdot (n+4)^{n/2 -1}
 \cdots  (2 n - 1) \cdot (2 n) >  3^{1} \cdot 4^{1} \cdot 5^2 \cdot 6^2 \cdots (n+1)^{n/2}
$$

There are $(n-1)$ terms on both sides. Now we compare pairs of terms with the same exponent on the LHS and RHS and it is evident that in each of these pairs,
the base on the LHS is always larger than the base on the RHS. This proves the claim.